# datetimepicker sets time to device time on when clicking anywhere outside android

Tags: android, dialog, datetimepicker

I have a Timepicker with EditText. Below are the scenarios:

1. On editing the time picker, it sets the value to the edittext.That
   works fine
2. Above and below timepicker, there are EditTexts. On editing the
       EditText which is above and below(whichever) the Timepicker EditText
       automatically changes the time to device time.

I don't want to change the time to device time. How do I fix this? Is this a bug?

I have tried following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27448272/android-datepicker-is-setting-the-value-even-i-touch-outside-of-the-datepicker) but no help.

Comment: show your current code

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a builder to show the date picker

if yes

include this too

```
  builder.setCancelable(false);
```

Comment: I am using custom time picker dialog, ur fix doesn't work :(

Comment: are you using property like `wheel` and all?

Comment: do check the link [custom-datepicker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29173520/creating-custom-datepicker-dialog)