# Android cancel DatePickerDialog when Touch Outside

Tags: android, datepickerdialog

andorid cancel DatePickerDialog when Touch Outside
the code follow is not work

```
    datePickerDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
    datePickerDialog.setCancelable(true);
```

Comment: datePickerDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27448272/android-datepicker-is-setting-the-value-even-i-touch-outside-of-the-datepicker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somethinh like this,

Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context)

dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);

Answer (score 0):

datePickerDialog.setCancelable(true); or use only datePickerDialog.setCancelable(true);

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please feel free to take a [tour](//stackoverflow.com/tour) of the site, and if you need additional help with the site, check [this](//stackoverflow.com/help) out. Oh, and if you ever run into issues that the help page doesn't cover, feel free to ask on [meta](//meta.stackoverflow.com/). Also, please don't post answers on obviously bad questions! [See: **Should one advise on off topic questions?**](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276572)